# Ggplot with patterns and colors - legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to make a bar plot by country and sources of income. As I have 13 income components by each single country, I'm using colors and patterns to make a clearer distinction. Here a subsample of the data:

```
 structure(list(country = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
 "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria", 
 "Austria", "Austria", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
 "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", 
 "Belgium", "Belgium", "Germany"), `relative contributions` = c(1.12873709201813, 
  0.190666541457176, 0.0881932526826859, -0.0167537834495306, -0.0258312318474054, 
  0.215001374483109, -0.00148478976916522, -0.000572826422285289, 
  -0.0133617669343948, -0.00855048839002848, -0.00286591215990484, 
  -0.55317747592926, 1.43853068351746, 0.12194737046957, 0.0775384828448296, 
  -0.00403465563431382, -0.0196540541946888, -0.0183424148708582, 
  -0.0311897918581963, -0.00196828553453088, -0.00494809495285153, 
  -0.0225886180996895, -0.000150939886225387, -0.535139620304108, 
  1.23838818073273), component = c("Employee wages", "Self-employment", 
  "Capital", "Private transfers", "Unemployment", "Old-age + survivors", 
 "Sick + disability", "Education", "Social exclusion allowances", 
 "Family allowances", "Housing allowances", "Taxes", "Employee wages", 
 "Self-employment", "Capital", "Private transfers", "Unemployment", 
 "Old-age + survivors", "Sick + disability", "Education", "Social exclusion allowances", 
 "Family allowances", "Housing allowances", "Taxes", "Employee wages"
 )), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ))
```

Up to now, I was able to produce the following plot:

```
 pat <- c('bricks', 'fishscales', 'verticalsaw', 'crosshatch', 'checkboard', 'octagons', 'verticalbrics', 'vertical', 'right45', 'hs_horizontal', 'horizontalsaw', 'hs_cross', 'hexagons')

ggplot(relative) + 
 geom_bar_pattern(aes(x=country, y=`relative contributions`, fill=factor(component), pattern_type=factor(component)), stat="identity", position="stack", width = 0.6, pattern='magick',  pattern_scale = 0.5, colour="black") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="Income components", values = mycolors) +  scale_pattern_type_discrete(choices = pat, guide = 'none') + 
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1,2), breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 7)) + 
 theme_bw() +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, vjust=1)) + xlab("") + ylab("") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))   `
```

Which results in the following figure:
[image]

However, the legend does not report the pattern. If I offset guide="none" I will have two legends, but is there a way to have a unique legend (as in the current version) reporting both the colors and the patterns?

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `guide="none"` to show the patterns in the legend but add `name="Income components"` to `scale_pattern_xxx` so that the guides get merged. Otherwise the scales have different names and you end up with two separate legends.

Note: I switched to `scale_fill_discrete` as `mycolors` was not provided.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

ggplot(relative) +
  geom_bar_pattern(aes(x = country, y = `relative contributions`, fill = factor(component), pattern_type = factor(component)), stat = "identity", position = "stack", width = 0.6, pattern = "magick", 
                   pattern_scale = 0.5, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Income components") +
  scale_pattern_type_discrete(name = "Income components", choices = pat) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 2), breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 7)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried your solution - exactly copying and paste - and I get the same graph, but without the pattern in the legend. What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi Luca. Unfortunately I have no clue what could be the issue. Usual suggestion would be to restart R, update your pkgs ... FYI I'm running R 4.2.0, ggplot2 3.3.6 ggpattern 0.4.2 magick 2.7.3 on a Windows machine.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same versions for all pkgs and R, but on a Mac. I will try on a Windows just to check. Many thanks!

Comment: Hm. Just tried on my Mac and works there fine too. So probably not a Mac issue. However, I just saved the plot as a png and a pdf. In the png I lose the patterns in the plot, in the pdf I don't get any patterns in the legend.

Comment: Still not working on my Mac, while it perfectly works on Windows, even when saving the plot as a png/jpeg.